# Email spoofing in Linux (received message with no subject and content)

Tags: linux, email, telnet

I'm trying to send email using telnet in terminal of my linux. I have connection with telnet now

I have typed the commands below successfully. Unfortunately, I only receive the message with no subject and content. Please help me on how to fix this for it to have the content I typed in the terminal line.

```
telnet mail.dispostable.com 25
ehlo
MAIL FROM:<fakeme@email.com>
RCPT TO:<ss121q@dispostable.com>
DATA
SUBJECT: Test mail
I'm having a hard time on making this appear.
.
quit
```

After every line typed and entered, message always appears. (.) is used to end the message and proceed to sending.

By the way I got this all from http://dougvitale.wordpress.com/2011/12/31/send-spoofed-emails-with-telnet/

Answer (score 0):

You need to better comply with [the standard](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2822.txt).

- You need a blank line between your message headers and the body text.
- You should at least give `From:` and `To:` headers to avoid getting `Apparently-from:` added by the MTA.

Try this:

```
MAIL FROM: <fakeme@email.com>
RCPT TO: <ss121q@dispostable.com>
DATA
From: fakeme@email.com
To: ss121q@dispostable.com
Subject: Test mail

I'm having a hard time on making this appear.
.
QUIT
```